# hacking router through physical connection

Tags: networking, router

I have a TpLink Router and I have set strong security on it, but my cousin has a physical connection to my device through which he runs his computer, but whenever I change me wifi password then he finds it and connects his mobile too, I want to ask that if has a physical connection to my router then can he break into my router's administrative settings and see the password ?? If yes then how to secure it ??

Comment: Locking him out of the wifi isn't going to help if he knows the log/pass for the router's admin page. That's the one you need to change first.

Comment: yes, you can access the routers administrative settings from a physical connection. Have you tried changing the admin password? Its also possible (but less likely) that wifi security is not as strong as you think and they are hacking into your network. are you using WPA2 with AES (no TKIP)? keep in mind, you can never keep a determined adversary out if they have physical access to the hardware.

Comment: Anyone with physical access can press the WPS button and connect without knowing the password. On my TP-Link router this function can be disabled in the router menu.

Comment: @FrankThomas, I have set different passwords for login and wifi, I think he uses some kind of software to break in my administrative settings

Comment: that's not very feasible. unless your password is very short or is used in common attack dictionaries, its very unlikely that he was able to brute force the password in less than weeks at best and more likely years (potentially lots of years).  its more likely that he has installed malware on one of your devices to monitor you logging in (thought that's pretty unlikely unless he's both motivated and knowledgeable (and more than a little unscrupulous)  ).

Comment: If WPS is enabled, then router is not secured; even if you have very strong password.

Comment: Physical meaning wired connection? What makes you think he is getting into the administrative settings? If you are just finding port forwards, it's probably just upnp enabled in the router. Disable WPS it's totally broken.(wps pixie).  I would factory reset, enable strong passwords for the administrator gui, and put a strong password in for the WPA2-PSK. 16 digit alpha-numerical with special characters.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from securing your router, you can also talk to your cousin about this to convince him to not do what you do not want.

Now wireless routers have a password for wireless access, and a username/password for the configuration.

By default the configuration login is something as easy to guess as admin/admin or admin/password, or sometimes even no password at all!

If you did not come across a login screen when changing the wifi password, your router does not have a configuration password set, you should be able to find the option to set it in the router configuration where you changed the wifi password, but under labels like "system" or "security".

Even if you have a configuration password, i strongly advise you to change it if it is the default one, even if it looks hard to guess or remember.